# Why do GIF images automatically lock the base layer in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, pixelation

When I open a `.gif` image in Photoshop - non animated - it always locks automatically and you cannot unlock it. Aside from that when try try to add text it will make a red block and convert the text to bitmap.

You annoyingly have to copy and paste the document into a new document. Then layer from there.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's due to the Index Color mode. GIF and PNG8 use a locked color palette, therefore the layer gets locked to prevent unsupported changes. It's also why the layer is titled *Index*.

To unlock it choose `Image > Mode > RGB` from the menu.

Comment: Can this be as a default?

Comment: No. GIF and PNG8 images will always open in Index color mode, that's simply how those images work. When you save a GIF or PNG8, it gets saved to Index mode as well.

Comment: I'm not an expert by far, but I do use Photoshop nearly every day at work. I cannot for the life of me understand WHY this is necessary? I find it to be a huge pain in the butt to have to unlock or duplicate an image because it always comes into Photoshop locked and unable to manipulate. Shouldn't this be a choice someone makes instead of a default?

Comment: @user22965: they do this so that the file is not altered without direct user intervention.

Comment: You can also simply assign a shortcut (via actions) to change the image mode to RGB and it will unlock the *Index* layer.

Comment: You also don't usually WANT to be editing GIFs. Ideally, you're editing the original PSD rather than the exported GIF.

Comment: This drove me nuts for years, so I finally figured out a way to automatically unlock gifs/jpgs/pngs when you open them: http://www.chrisfletcher.net/automatically-unlock-background-layer-photoshop/